# Can't Perform action on click yes in Jquery based confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a template it is using some fallr confirmation or alert boxes features. It has a code for confirmation box, its working fine but its not working according to my requirement..means

i have one link for delete row from table like:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/del_menu/<?php echo $values->id; ?>" rel="tooltip-top" title="Delete" id="confirm">
```

when i click on it its showing a dialog box who ask for 'Yes' and 'Cancel' it's jquery code is:

```
 $('#confirm').click(function(ev) {
                var clicked = function(){
                    $.fallr('hide');
                    return true;
                };


                $.fallr('show', {
                    buttons : {
                        button1 : {text: 'Yes', danger: true, onclick: clicked},
                        button2 : {text: 'Cancel', onclick: function(){$.fallr('hide')}}
                    },
                    content : '<p>Are you sure you want to delete menu?</p>',
                    icon    : 'error'
                });

                ev.preventDefault();
            });
```

in this code i just want to edit one thing..link action should only perform when i click on yes..but now i have added `ev.preventDefault()` it's disable my link and it's also not working on click yes... is any body knows how to handle this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the user in your clicked handler by giving the destination of the link to window.location:

```
 $('#confirm').click(function(ev) {
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            var clicked = function(){
                // This will redicrect the browser to the given location.
                window.location = target;
            };


            $.fallr('show', {
                buttons : {
                    button1 : {text: 'Yes', danger: true, onclick: clicked},
                    button2 : {text: 'Cancel', onclick: function(){$.fallr('hide')}}
                },
                content : '<p>Are you sure you want to delete menu?</p>',
                icon    : 'error'
            });

            ev.preventDefault();
        });
```